# Проблема с JOINами в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите плиз. Задача этого запроса. Вернуть посты, которые имеют фото. То есть посты, id которых имеются в таблице photo.

Проблема в том, что если в таблице photo хранятся две записи c id post. То этот запрос продублирует посты. Если 5 фото в одном посте(5 записей в таблице photo), то запрос вернет 5 одних и тех же постов

```
    SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_log = posts.tag_id                                   
RIGHT JOIN photo ON photo.id_post =  posts.id_post
WHERE posts.tag_id = '@politics'
```

Comment: Т.е. posts.id_post может иметь значение null или не null? Так на него и проверяйте. Или что значит фраза "которые имеют записи с posts.id_post в таблице photo"?

Comment: @alexlz обновил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил проблему подзапросом

```
   'posts.id_post' IN (SELECT photo.id_post FROM photo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_log = posts.tag_id                                   
RIGHT JOIN photo ON photo.id_post =  posts.id_post
WHERE posts.tag_id = '@politics' and
photo.id IS NOT NULL
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null

Comment: не чего не изменилось. У меня RIGHT JOIN photo как-бы возвращает более одной строки и из-за этого пост дублируется

Comment: @KARTON да, всё нормально. Отсеиваются несуществующие (или имеющие photo.id == NULL), а для ненулевых -- размножает по количеству строк в photo

Comment: @Zow, так добавьте в SELECT DISTINCT(photo.id)

Comment: в таблице photo у каждой записи должен быть свой id. photo.id IS NOT NULL выбереш только те записи у которых есть фото.  
После чего тебе надо только с групировать GROUP BY post.id и вуаля.

Comment: @KARTOH за такие советы надо наказывать. По одной причине -- такая дурь будет работать в mysql, но другие сервера будут посылать автора лесом. Разумеется, решение ему нужно сейчас и для mysql, но к уродским решениям лучше не привыкать. (Уродство заключается в том, что mysql позволяет выдавать в результат поля, не входящие в group by без агрегатных функций. За такие расширения надо бы бить и бить больно)